# CodeIgniter: set_value() or post() - what is faster and what is the best practice to store data into database

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-2

**Background**
Using `Codeigniter` with `form_helper` and `form_validation` to do some form processing. *Form has been validated successfully* in the `controller`.

**Now we need to put this data into the database using the `model` class.**

**Assumptions**

Lets assume our form has several input elements (e.g. >20).

**Question**
Which of the following code snippets will be more efficient? `Both snippets are obviously inside the controller method to which the form submits data.`

*Code Snippet 1*

```
if ($this->form_validation->run())
{
    // validation successful, now collect the values in a variable to pass it to the model.
    $form_data['field1'] = $this->form_validation->set_value('field1');
    $form_data['field2'] = $this->form_validation->set_value('field2');
    // AND SO ON
    $form_data['fieldN'] = $this->form_validation->set_value('fieldN');

    // Now put this data into database.
    $this->corresponding_model->write_to_db($form_data);
}
```

*Code Snippet 2*

```
if ($this->form_validation->run())
{
    // validation successful, now collect the values in a variable to pass it to the model.
    $form_data['field1'] = $this->input->post('field1');
    $form_data['field2'] = $this->input->post('field2');
    // AND SO ON
    $form_data['fieldN'] = $this->input->post('fieldN');

    // Now put this data into database.
    $this->corresponding_model->write_to_db($form_data);
}
```

**So essentially what I am asking is:** What is better to get the post data for some arbitrary form element? `$this->input->post` or `$this->form_validation->set_value()` ?

**PS:** If we look the the `set_value()` and `post()` functions in the code (please see below), obviously `set_value()` is going to be faster as `post()` loops through the entire `$_POST`. So in a sense it is also about what is the best practice?

**Form_validation.php, set_value() method**

```
public function set_value($field = '', $default = '')
{
    if ( ! isset($this->_field_data[$field]))
    {
        return $default;
    }

    // If the data is an array output them one at a time.
    //     E.g: form_input('name[]', set_value('name[]');
    if (is_array($this->_field_data[$field]['postdata']))
    {
        return array_shift($this->_field_data[$field]['postdata']);
    }

    return $this->_field_data[$field]['postdata'];
}
```

**Input.php, post() method**

```
function post($index = NULL, $xss_clean = FALSE)
{
    // Check if a field has been provided
    if ($index === NULL AND ! empty($_POST))
    {
        $post = array();

        // Loop through the full _POST array and return it
        foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $key)
        {
            $post[$key] = $this->_fetch_from_array($_POST, $key, $xss_clean);
        }
        return $post;
    }

    return $this->_fetch_from_array($_POST, $index, $xss_clean);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Both functions will return the modified value if rules have been run on the input.

When you want to read a post value from form, **USE** `$this->input->post()`.

`set_value()` is used to re-populate a form has failed validation. 
There is no additional filtering on it, so it faster but I prefer you should use `$this->input->post()` for the secure.

Comment: **First:** `set_value()` will never modify value, it just returns the value of a field [from `$_POST`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Form_validation.php#L324-L342).

Comment: **Second:** If you want to read a post value you can use `$_POST[$field]` directly, not necessarily `$this->input->post()`!

Comment: **Third:** `set_value()` will return value even if form validation runs without error, and in terms of performance it doesn't have any advantage compared to the `$this->input->post()`, unless you enable XSS filtering on `post()` method.

Answer (score 2):

While the `$this->form_validation->set_value()` **might be** faster in some cases, [take a look at the benchmark below], the most important difference  between these two methods is preparing a **XSS filtering option** in `$this->input->post()` method.

### Form Validation :: set_value() Functionality

In *Form Validation Class* , [all fields are stored in `$this->_field_data`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Form_validation.php#L324-L342) property, the values come from `$_POST` directly and `$this->form_validation->set_value()` method just [returns data from `$this->_field_data`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Form_validation.php#L738-L743).

### Input :: post() Functionality

*Input Class* prepares a XSS filtering option, you might consider using it to store values into database.

**Note:**
Please note that `$this->input->post()` method [does **NOT** loop through the entire `$_POST` by default](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Input.php#L175-L185), unless it is called without a specific `$index` parameter.

### Benchmark

System Information:

**CPU:** `Intel Core-i5 760 @ 2.80 GHz` **RAM:** `2.00 GB`.

**Test case:** *A 30-character string* text field.

```
set_rules()                   0.0000
Check Validation              0.0003
set_value()                   0.0000
Form Validation (Overall)     0.0024

post() without XSS filtering  0.0000
post() with XSS filtering     0.0002
```

---

### Conclusion

If you need to perform a XSS filtering before storing values into database I recommend using CodeIgniter Input class. also, there are more **Security Filtering** operations that Input Class serves, explained in [CodeIgniter User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes code snippet #1, sometimes - #2. In most cases $this->input->post() is much faster. But it can depends of environment code and data. You can easy check what is faster in your case:

```
public function codeSnippet1(){
ob_start();
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
// your code here

ob_end_flush();
}

public function codeSnippet2(){
ob_start();
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
// your code here

ob_end_flush();
}
```

Then call this functions and match results.