# set_value() not working without having a validation rule

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-2

I have found that when I use `set_value()` in a Codeigniter 2 form, to repopulate a form field, it only returns a value if I have a validation rule set for this input.

Which is fine if I am validating a field, but not fine if it is an optional input with no validation.

So what I plan to do now as standard for every single form I process, is add this little hack to create 'empty' rules before adding any genuine validation rules;

```
//iterate over every posted value and create an empty rule for it.
foreach ($this->input->post() as $key => $value) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($key);
}
```

Then if I have any 'real' rules I will add them afterwards so they overwrite the previous empty rule.

What I want to know is, is there another way to do this, built into the framework? It seems like a bit of an omission that these values are not available to the `set_value()` function until they have a rule, which makes me wonder if I have missed a configuration option?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `set_value`, you can use `$this->input->post()` to get its submitted value.

For ex:

```
<input name='test_name' type='text' value = '<?php echo $this->input->post("test_name");?>' />
```

Comment: I'm not keen on this solution because I use set_value() with a default parameter too, this would be too long-winded to put into the view. I guess I could write my own set_value() function instead, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yes. You can create your own helper to get value with default value. Like `my_set_value()`.

Answer (score 1):

> If you're using the validation library, **you have to set at least a
>   validation rule** for your field to get set_value() form helper
>   function to work.

If you're interested to know the reason behind this and/or how `set_*()` functions work, you can refer to my answer here:

- [set_select() helper function is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724479/set-select-helper-function-is-not-working/21734271#21734271)

---

In this particular instance, I suggest using `$_POST[$key]` to fetch the posted value of the field. Because [`Input::post()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209442/codeigniter-set-value-or-post-what-is-faster-and-what-is-the-best-practic/17212314#17212314) method doesn't do anything more than reading the value from `$_POST`.

Thus, you could get the value as follows:

```php
$value = isset($_POST[$field]) ? $_POST[$field] : 'default value';

// Or echo off the errors
$value = @$_POST[$field]) ?: 'default value'; // PHP 5.3+ syntax
```

*(Check the [result](https://eval.in/117448)).*

---

You could also extend the CI form helper in order to to add a new helper function:

**application\helpers\MY_form_helper.php**

```php
if (! function_exists('get_value')) {
    function get_value($field = '', $default = '')
    {
        if (! isset($_POST[$field]))
        {
            if (count($_POST) === 0 AND $default !== '')
            {
                return $default;
            }
            return '';
        }

        return $_POST[$field];
    }
}
```

Then could use the helper function as follows:

```
<input name="my_field" type="text" value="<?php echo get_value('my_field', 'Default Value'); ?>">
```